# Using regex to move multiple files

Tags: python, regex

I'm really new to python and looking to organize hundreds of files and want to use regex to move them to the correct folders.

Example: I would like to move 4 files into different folders.

File A has "USA" in the name

File B has "Europe" in the name

File C has both "USA" and "Europe" in the name

Fild D has "World" in the name

Here is what I am thinking but I don't think this is correct

```
shutil.move('Z:\local 1\[.*USA.*]', 'Z:\local 1\USA')
shutil.move('Z:\local 1\[.*\(Europe\).*]', 'Z:\local 1\Europe')
shutil.move('Z:\local 1\[.*World.*]', 'Z:\local 1\World')
```

Comment: what do you want to do with File C?

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the files in a directory and move them in a new folder if their names matches a given regular expression as follows:

```py
import os
import re
import shutil

for filename in os.listdir('path/to/some/directory'):
    if re.match(r'Z:\\local 1\\[.*USA.*]+', filename):
        shutil.move(os.path.join('path/to/some/directory', filename), 'Z:\local 1\USA')
    elif re.match(r'Z:\\local 1\\[.*\(Europe\).*]+', filename):
        shutil.move(os.path.join('path/to/some/directory', filename), 'Z:\local 1\Euro')
    # and so forth
```

However, `os.listdir` shows only the direct subfolders and files, but it does not iterate deeper. If you want to analyze all the files recursively in a given folder use the [`os.walk`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) method.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of `shutil.move`, it needs two things:

- src, which is a path of a source file
- dst, which is a path to the destination folder.

It says that `src` and `dst` should be **paths**, not regular expressions.

What you have is `os.listdir()` which list files in a directory.

So what you need to do is to list files, then try to match file names against regular expressions. If you get a match, then you know where the file should go.

That said, you still need to decide what to do with option C that matches both 'USA' and 'Europe'.

For added style points you can put pairs of (regex, destination_path) into an array, tuple or map; in this case you can add any number of rules without changing or duplicating the logic.